# Performance issue of SQL

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have three tables `Address`,`Item` and `Item_Location`

`Address` table:

```
address_id | street_nm | street_nbr | city    | zipcode | ...
-------------------------------------------------------------
   3       | Zebra     |   333      | Houston |  77777  | 
   4       | Yak       |   333      | Houston |  77777  |
```

`Item_Location` table:

```
item_location_id | address_id
------------------------------
   2             |   3
   4             |   4
```

`Item` table:

```
item_id | location_a (FK_item_location_id) | location_b (FK_item_location_id)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1      |   2                              |    4
```

I'm running a search condition: `Find out items at a/b location based on address given`. As you've seen there is location reference in two columns of item.

Query to search is:

```
select Item.item_id, 
from 
  Item, (select address_id, item_location_id 
         from address, Item_location il 
         where street_nm like '%zebra%' and street_nbr = 333 
           and il.address_id = address.address_id) addr
where 
    (addr.item_location_id = item.location_a or 
     addr.item_location_id = item.location_b)
```

This query runs very slow as there are no indexes on the `Address` table and I cannot add one. Is there anything else that I should have done to improve the speed? Right now if I run using the address table it takes around 20secs to return the result.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s but, I've seen a debate some where in stack overflow on the same. And the performance does not matter much for older way of joins vs ANSI join. (Ofcoz i'll dig through your link further on the same).

Comment: how many rows are in each table respectively any how many rows do you expect to be returned?

Comment: @beherenow Each of the table has about 10 Million records. I'm guessing Address has even more - about 100 million. The query i've given is a tiny bit of a 600 line query(and made short for understanding) . The result may vary depending on the location. Say a location has more than one Item then it should return that many .. i'm seeing the result can be between 1 and 10000 or may be more

Comment: 20 seconds don't seem entirely unreasonable given the numbers. there could be a bottleneck in the execution plan but it is equally possible that it is just time spent full-scanning and hash-joining - technically, your 10M rows table could be ~100gb size depending on the number of columns and their types. can you post the execution plan of this query with execution statistics?

Comment: expample: http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_xplan.html; add gather_plan_statistics hint to your query and post DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CUSROR output.

Comment: It's not about **performance** - but about **readability and maintainability** for the future

Answer (score -1):

This is a really ugly query. Besides the fact that there are errors, you are ignoring a lot of best practices and though it may not substantially improve your performance, writing queries that are easy to read will greatly improve your ability to maintain the queries in the future. First things first: if you use aliases, you should use them consistently, both by aliasing all your tables and by prefixing all of your columns. Also, you should really think about the spacing. Just by changing those two things (and a few other issues), we get this:

```
select  i.item_id
from    Item i,
    (select ad.address_id,
            il.item_location_id
     from address ad,
          Item_location il 
     where
           ad.street_nm like '%zebra%' and ad.street_nbr = 333 
           and il.address_id = ad.address_id) addr   
where
      addr.item_location_id = i.location_a 
      or addr.item_location_id = i.location_b
```

Wow! This is so much more readable. Now, I can clearly see that you are using the deprecated version of table joins and that should change to an explicit join (yay standardization). Also, I can clearly see that you do not need the subquery for this query. Removing the subquery will most likely improve the performance of your query (it may only be a little bit, but we like any and all gains). Lets fix those issues:

```
select  i.item_id
from    Item i
   join address ad 
       on (addr.item_location_id = il.location_a 
           or addr.item_location_id = il.location_b)
   join Item_location il 
       on il.address_id = ad.address_id
where
      ad.street_nm like '%zebra%' and ad.street_nbr = 333
```

Suddenly this is looking so much better. Now we can really hone in on the biggest issue (in my opinion) in your query.

```
on (addr.item_location_id = il.location_a 
or addr.item_location_id = il.location_b)
```

Fun fact, because you were not selecting or aliasing anything as location_a and location_b in your original query, it would not have executed and you would have received errors. I'm just going to go ahead and guess that this is killing your query. Originally, I could not see this big fat `or` hanging out as a join condition. My recommendation is to split this into two queries and throw in a union all:

```
select  i.item_id
from    Item i
   join address ad 
       on addr.item_location_id = il.location_a 
   join Item_location il 
       on il.address_id = ad.address_id
where
      ad.street_nm like '%zebra%' and ad.street_nbr = 333

union all

select  i.item_id
from    Item i
   join address ad 
       on addr.item_location_id = il.location_b
   join Item_location il 
       on il.address_id = ad.address_id
where
      ad.street_nm like '%zebra%' and ad.street_nbr = 333
```

Without indexing, I think this query is going to be your best bet in terms of performance. Even if it doesn't speed things up too much, look at how much prettier it is! The future developers at your organization will thank you.

Comment: your query actually looks less readable and changing "or" to "union all" has nothing to do with better performance - you are scanning the same table twice.

Comment: @beherenow I think the or in the join condition would probably hurt, but you may be right about the extra scanning causing more issues. If I was the OP, I'd probably try a few things out and see how long the various queries actually take to run. Please note the query before marc's edit. I would say the extra spacing absolutely improves readability.

Comment: @beherenow: It depends a lot on the engine. In many cases where there is an `or` join, the database will decide to scan the table twice on its own.